# Insert data from txt file to database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in a .txt file.

```
4654664
6545645646
54564121452
564754412
5456545
```

I want to insert this data in db using php

```
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$user= "infdgfg";
$pass= "98fgfgdghf6";
$db="xxxxx";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$file = fopen("oxxxkxxn.txt","r");  

while(! feof($file))
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO xxxxx( xxxxx ) VALUES ('($file)')"; //Insert every read line from txt to mysql database
mysql_query($sql);
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

but this is not working.

`(Resource id #4)`
`(Resource id #4)`
`(Resource id #4)`

this error.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Please make an effort to properly format your code. Also, you say `this error`, but you don't list an error? How are we supposed to help fix that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fopen returns a file pointer (that's your Resources).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

After opening your file you then need to use fgets to get the data line by line.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

So you would do something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO xxxxx( xxxxx ) VALUES ('" . fgets($file) . "')";
```